# OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'test_db_14'")

Tags: mysql, django, testing

When executing django tests using parallel command Im facing the above error. Im using MySQL 5.6 for test db.

Answer (score -1):

With MySQL, you need to manually create your database too.

```
mysql -u root -p

mysql> CREATE DATABASE test_db_14;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

finally run your syncdb.

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: isn't test db supposed to be auto created?

Comment: @user3382968 As i already mention you've to do it manually in MySQL

Comment: Can you explain why i need not create any database if im not using parallel command?

Comment: @Mr.Robot no it is supposed to be created automatically